# Sharing a calendar with a service account

Tags: google-calendar-api

Subject: 
Description:
We are trying to share a calendar with a service account.

We created a project and a Service Account (for said project) on the Google Developers Console. Then we tried sharing a calendar with this Service Account ID email

I noticed google service accounts have a domain of the form iam.gserviceaccount.com so we can't share a calendar from one of our company's account

Our company's policy dictates we shouldn't set the 'external sharing options' to other than 'sharing busy/free' but we need more data. As stated in the previous paragraph, we can't share the calendar with our internal service account because of the domain mismatch

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround:

- First create a calendar in the service account (with the API)
- Then share the calendar with the organization (with the API)
- Export/Import the events of the existing calendar (remove old)
- Now you can access the calendar through the API, and edit it in the organization's accounts